# ZF2 Bulk insert using INSERT INTO .... SELECT from a table to same table

Tags: php, zend-framework2, bulkinsert, insert-into

I am trying to do a bulk copy of some records from a table into the same table with one field changed. But I am not able to find the correct method in ZF2 for it.

My existing table looks like this :
CoID -- CatCode -- CategoryName

PP   -- auto    --  Auto

PP   -- Mt      -- Metro

PP   -- Taxi    -- Taxi

I want to run this SQL Query :

insert into expcatmaster 
select 'RY', CatCode, CategoryName from expcatmaster where CoID = 'PP'

I am not able to find a way to put the constant 'RY' into the code (using ZF2).
The code in my CopyCategoryTable.php is as below :

```
public function insCategory($FromCoID, $ToCoID) {
    $SelCol = array(
        'CoID',
        'CatCode',
        'CategoryName',
    );

    $adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
    $sql = new Sql($adapter);
    $SelQry =$sql->select();
    $SelQry->columns($SelCol);
    $SelQry->from('ExpcatMaster');
    $SelQry->where(array('CoID' => $FromCoID));
    echo $SelQry->getSqlString();

    $InsQry = $sql->insert();
    $InsQry->into('ExpcatMaster');
    $InsQry->select($SelQry);
    $InsData = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($InsQry);
    echo $InsQry->getSqlString();

    $this->tableGateway = $InsData->execute();

}
```

How do i replace the actual value of CoID from the select table with $ToCoID i have passed to the function ? Tried google and searched in this forum but cant seem to work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method for bulk insert in ZF (Zend\Db),
so you have to write a method for that.

[Zend\Db\Sql\Sql multiple batch inserts](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4028)

The bulk insert is supported in MySQL but not in all databases...
Check discussion on link.

You can execute raw SQL query for this case:

```
$parameters = ['name 1', 'desc 1', 'name 2', 'desc 2'];
$sql        = 'INSERT INTO table (name, description) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?);';
$resultSet  = $this->adapter->query($sql, $parameters);

return $resultSet->getAffectedRows();
```

Comment: Hi. Wouldnt that be slow if we have a large number of rows to copy from one table to another ? In my code, the SQL Query (its MySQL) is being properly generated but it is not executing. I can take the same query and run it in the query manager in phpmyadmin, it works. But in ZF2 it does not execute.

Comment: Ok, i have used the raw SQL Query and put in an Insert Into ... Select query to do the bulk insert. Thanks for pointing the way out.

Comment: I cant figure out how to "approve". (sorry, i am new to stackoverflow)